# Will using tilde-greater-than (~>) with pre release version (rc1/rc2) update the gem when it is released?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the pre release version of the koala gem: `gem "koala", "~> 3.0.0.rc2"`. Will it use the `3.0.0` version when it is released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't as mentioned in the [guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint):

> Using ~> with prerelease versions will restrict you to prerelease
>   versions only